# How to change "Secure Login Module - Secure base url" without login?

Tags: 7, users

I have installed [Secure Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin) with Secure base URL setting on a live site, and clone that into a different domain for testing. The "/user" page has no login form because the Secure base URL should be different. How can I change this URL without login? Where is this data in phpMyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the variables table. Variable name is securelogin_base_ssl, value like `s:4:"theurl";`

Comment: I only see the securelogin_base_url not securelogin_base_ssl

Comment: Update the securelogin_base_url actually work :)